# Computer freeze after connecting to usb flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, freeze

I tried to connect my WD500G mechanical drive to my computer using the case provided USB-A port. Recently when I connected, the system freeze and keyboard light went off. But other things work normally (CPU fans, graphic card lights, RGB lights ect.)
If I plug in the drive before power on, everything is good.

Any suggestion on what could be wrong would be appreciated!

Here is my config info:

```
MOBO: Gigabyte B450 Pro Wifi
CPU: AMD R5 3600
RAM: Gskill Ripjaw 16G*4 3200 MHz
Graphic card: MSI Gaming Trio RTX 2080Ti
SSD: Samsung 970 EVO 500G
Flash drive: WD ELEMENTS SE PORTABLE 500GB APAC (WDBABV5000ABK-PESN)
Case: Cosair 275R 
PSU: Modular 850W Gold
OS: Win 10 Pro Insider Preview 21301.1010
```

Comment: The power supply might be a bit weak.

Comment: My PSU is 850W Gold. Shouldn't be a problem though... Could be my USB connection wire oxidize and cause short circuit? I bought it 10+ yrs ago and still use today...